# Checking Key in multiple dimensional array

Tags: php, arrays, key, key-value

M having multidimensional array and i want to check the key `"Apple"` if exist in it ,
if it is exist then i wan to get the `Price` of that Apple.

I have tried [Array_key_exists()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-key-exists.php) function , but it is applicable to only one dimensional array,

```
array(1) {
    [0]=>
        array(1) {
            ["Apple"]=>
                array(2) {
                    ["Color"]=>"Red"
                    ["Price"]=>int(50)
                }
            }
}
```

How can I get the price of the Apple if it exist in array?

Comment: is the data structure fixed? i mean, are you going to have fixed(one that you have shown) structure of array?

Comment: @BhavikShah only the first array will  change with foreach loop

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use a recursive function to achive this

```
function getPrice($array, $name) {
    if (isset($array[$name])) {
        return $array[$name]["Price"];
    }

    foreach ($array as $value) {
        if (is_array($value)) {
            $price = getPrice($value, $name);
            if ($price) {
                return $price;
            }
        }
    }

    return false;
}
```

Comment: its better to add else after first if(isse($array[$name]))

Comment: why? that isn't good coding style.. you should prevent deep nesting

Comment: please help, m getting Fatal error</b>:  Maximum function nesting level of '100' reached, aborting! when m trying to run that execute that function

Answer (score 1):

Just iterate (in a recursive way) over all yours array(s) and check for each if `array_key_exists()` or (maybe better) `isset()`

Just like

```
function myFinder($bigArray)
{
 $result = false;
 if(array_key_exist($key,$bigArray)) return $bigArray[$key];
 foreach($bigArray as $subArray)
 {
  if(is_array($subArray)
  {
   $result = $result or myFinder($subArray);
  }
 }
 return $result;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use foreach to loop over the array.

```
foreach ($array AS $fruit) {
    if(isset($fruit['Apple'])) {
        echo $fruit['Apple']['Price'];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$rows=array(
         array(
               'Apple'=>array('Color'=>'Red', 'Price'=>50)
              )
        );

function get_price($rows, $name)
{
   foreach($rows as $row) {
     if(isset($row[$name])) return $row[$name]['Price'];
   }
   return NULL;
}

echo get_price($rows, 'Apple');
```